# in this page hover is not working i dont know why and also footer is not taking 100% width even though i have given to it

Tags: php, html, css

Is my coding not correct or what's the problem in hover and footer. And i need to know about php mail program is that right or do I have mistakes in it i am not able to find errors because mail function doesnt work in local server.

```js
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

if($_POST["name"]==""||$_POST["email"]==""||$_POST["phone"]==""||$_POST["msg"]==""){
echo "Fill All Fields..";
}
else
{
$email=$_POST['email'];
$email= filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if (!$email){
echo "Invalid Sender's Email";
}
else{
$subject = $_POST['sub'];
$message = $_POST['msg'];
$headers = 'From:'. $email2 . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= 'Cc:'. $email2 . "\r\n";
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);

mail("recievers@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $headers);
echo "Your mail has been sent successfuly!";
}
}
}
?>
```

```css
#wrapper
{
width:100%;
height:auto; 
margin:0px;
background-color:orange;
}

#navbar
{
height:60px;
width:100%;
background-color:black;
color:white;
float:left;
    
}

 ul li
{
display: block;
position: relative;
padding:20px 20px;
float:left;
}
ul li a
{
 color:white;
}
#navbar a:hover
{
 color:red;
 padding:5px;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img 
  {
      width: 70%;
      height:15%;
      margin: auto;
      background-color:white;
  }

.thumbnail
{
height:300px;
width:300px;
padding:25px auto;
margin:5px;

}

.contact
{
width:60%;
height:300px;
background-color:grey;
padding:100px 25px;
float:left;
}

.enquiry
{
width:40%;
height:300px;
background-color:seagreen;
float:left;
padding-left:5px; 
}
input[type=text]:focus {
    border: 3px solid red;
}
input[type="text"] 
{
 margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}

.footer
{
height:60px;
width:100%;
background-color:black;
padding:10px;
color:white;
float:left;
}
.footer img
{
float:right;
margin:5px;
padding:5px;

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>student</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper"><!--start wrapper-->
<div id="navbar"><!--start nav-->
<ul>
<li><a href="home.html">Home</li>
<li><a href="about.html">About us</li>
<li><a href="services.html">Services</li>
<li><a href="products.html">Products</li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact us</li>
</ul>
</div><!--end nav-->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"><!--carasel start-->
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>

  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="D:\task\photo\h.jpg" alt="Home" height="400px">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Home</h3>
              </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="D:\task\photo\as.jpg" alt="About us" height="400px">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>About us</h3>
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="D:\task\photo\s.jpg" alt="Services" height="400px">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Services</h3>
             </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="D:\task\photo\p.jpg" alt="Products" height="400px"> 
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>products</h3>
             </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="D:\task\photo\c.jpg" alt="Contact us" height="400px">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Contact us</h3>
             </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div><!--end carosel-->

<div class="container-fluid text-center bg-grey"><!--boxes-->
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="D:\task\photo\i.jpg" alt="Innovation">
        <p><strong>Innovation</strong></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="D:\task\photo\cr.png" alt="Creative">
        <p><strong>Creativity</strong></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="D:\task\photo\po.jpg" alt="Positive">
        <p><strong>Positivity</strong></p>
              </div>
    </div>
</div><!--end boxes-->


<div id="con">
<div class="contact">
<h1>Address</h1>
<p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>
Abc private limited
no54,2ndstreet,
madipakkam,
chennai-67.
</p>
 <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> ABCPVT@gmail.com</p>
</div>
<div class="enquiry">
<h1>Enquiry Form</h1>

<table border="0" align="center">
<form name="form" action="email.php" id="form" method="post">
<tr>
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td><input name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Email</td>
<td><input name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Phone</td>
<td><input name="phone" placeholder="phonenumber" type="text" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Message</td>
<td><textarea name="msg" placeholder="Type your text here..."></textarea></td>
</tr>
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:center"><input id="send" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>

</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
copyrights &copy; to WWW.abcpvt.com
<img src="E:\photos\fb.png" alt="fb"/>
<img src="E:\photos\ln.png" alt="tweet"/>
<img src="E:\photos\tw.png" alt="linkedin"/>
</div>

</div><!--end wrapper-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried `body { margin: 0 }`

Comment: You have two problems that are unrelated to each other. Pleas post your mail problem and your HTML problem in separate questions.

Comment: now hover problem is done i need to know only about mail problem

Answer (score 1):

You can send mail from localhost with sendmail package , sendmail package is inbuild in XAMPP. So if you are using XAMPP then you can easily send mail from localhost.

for example you can configure `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` and `c:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini` for gmail to send mail.

in C:\xampp\php\php.ini find extension=php_openssl.dll and remove the semicolon from the beginning of that line to make SSL working for gmail for localhost.

in php.ini file find [mail function] and change

```
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com

smtp_port=587

sendmail_from = my-gmail-id@gmail.com

sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

Now Open C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini. Replace all the existing code in sendmail.ini with following code

```
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=my-gmail-id@gmail.com
auth_password=my-gmail-password
force_sender=my-gmail-id@gmail.com
```

Now you have done!! create php file with mail function and send mail from localhost.

PS: don't forgot to replace my-gmail-id and my-gmail-password in above code. Also, don't forget to remove duplicate keys if you copied settings from above. For example comment following line if there is another sendmail_path :

> sendmail_`path="C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"

in the php.ini file

Also remember to restart the server using the XAMMP control panel so the changes take effect.

**OR**

> [XMail](http://www.xmailserver.org/) or [hMailServer](https://www.hmailserver.com/) can do the trick.

**OR**

> try [PHPMailer](https://www.sitepoint.com/sending-emails-php-phpmailer/)

Answer (score 0):

**Hover is not working**

- It is because of carousel-inner is overflow in your `#navbar` div ,so use `overflow: hidden;`
- **footer is not taking 100%**!! Because footer is `#wrapper` child class, so 100% will take that parent(#wrapper) width only.Thus use `vw` instead of `%` and calculate margin-left property will solve your problem

  ```
  #navbar
  {
  height:60px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
  .footer
  {
  height:60px;
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: calc(-51vw + 50%);
  background-color:black;
  padding:10px;
  color:white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  }
  #con {
  margin-bottom: 23vw;
  }
  ```

Comment: send me@gamersudhar@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

The reasons for the footer not been 100%.

1. Its 100% per say but it becomes more than 100% after adding `padding:10px;`. To solve this you have to options. Its either you use `width:100%;` and add no `padding`, or you add `padding` and use `display:block;` instead of `width:100%;`
2. Secondly, you have a closing `div` missing for the `box`.

You have

```
<div class="container-fluid text-center bg-grey"><!--boxes-->
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="D:\task\photo\i.jpg" alt="Innovation">
        <p><strong>Innovation</strong></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="D:\task\photo\cr.png" alt="Creative">
        <p><strong>Creativity</strong></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="D:\task\photo\po.jpg" alt="Positive">
        <p><strong>Positivity</strong></p>
              </div>
        </div>
</div><!--end boxes-->
```

Instead of:

```
<div class="container-fluid text-center bg-grey"><!--boxes-->
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="D:\task\photo\i.jpg" alt="Innovation">
        <p><strong>Innovation</strong></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="D:\task\photo\cr.png" alt="Creative">
        <p><strong>Creativity</strong></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="D:\task\photo\po.jpg" alt="Positive">
        <p><strong>Positivity</strong></p>
              </div>
                </div>
    </div><!-- this is the missing closing div-->
</div><!--end boxes-->
```

3. Then lastly. You have to take away `float:left;` from the footer and use `clear:both;` instead. Doing this you will notice you have a better result.

Comment: @sudharsan Try this out, I figured out all your faults.