# line hover is not working and footer is not 100%

Tags: html, css

in this the line hover which i have given to a tag is not working.even when when i give hover to li its not working.at the last my footer in which i have set width to 100% is not taking full width.may i know why and wats the fault in my coding.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: orange;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: black;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 100;
}
#header {
  top: 0;
}
#footer {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: : 100;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
#footer img {
  float: right;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.company {
  width: 50%;
  height: 60px;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
}
#navbar {
  height: 60px;
  width: 50% background-color: black;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  float: left;
}
ul li a {
  color: white;
}
#navbar a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
.active {} #myCarousel {
  background-color: white;
  height: 370px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  width: 70%;
  height: 15%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
}
.thumbnail {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 25px auto;
  margin: 5px;
}
#con {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.contact {
  width: 60%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 100px 25px;
  float: left;
}
.enquiry {
  width: 40%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: seagreen;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
input[type=text]:focus {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
input[type="text"] {
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>student</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  @media only screen and (max-device-width:320px) @media only screen and (min-width:321px) and (max-device-width:480px) @media only screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-device-width:1024px) @media only screen and (min-device-width:1224px)

</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <!--start wrapper-->
    <div id="header">
      <!--start header-->
      <div class="company">
        <!--start company-->
        ABC PVT LIMITED
      </div>
      <!--end company-->
      <div class="navbar">
        <!--start nav-->
        <ul>
          <li><a class="active" href="home.html" />Home</li>
          <li><a href="about.html" />About us</li>
          <li><a href="services.html" />Services</li>
          <li><a href="products.html" />Products</li>
          <li><a href="contact.html" />Contact us</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--end nav-->
    </div>
    <!--end header-->
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!--carasel start-->
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>

      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <!--start carosel inner-->
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="../task/photo/h.jpg" alt="Home">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Home</h3>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="../task/photo/as.jpg" alt="About us">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>About Us</h3>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="item">
          <img src="../task/photo/s.jpg" alt="Services">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Services</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="../task/photo/p.jpg" alt="Products">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Products</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="../task/photo/c.jpg" alt="Contact us">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Contact Us</h3>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!--carosel inner end-->

      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!--end carosel-->

    <div class="container-fluid text-center bg-grey">
      <!--boxes-->

      <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="D:\task\photo\i.jpg" alt="Innovation">
            <p><strong>Innovation</strong>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="D:\task\photo\cr.png" alt="Creative">
            <p><strong>Creativity</strong>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="D:\task\photo\po.jpg" alt="Positive">
            <p><strong>Positivity</strong>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--end boxes-->


      <div id="con">
        <!--start con-->
        <div class="contact">
          <!-- start contact-->
          <h1>Address</h1>
          <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>
            Abc private limited no54,2ndstreet, madipakkam, chennai-67.
          </p>
          <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> ABCPVT@gmail.com</p>
        </div>
        <!--end contact-->
        <div class="enquiry">
          <!--start enquiry-->
          <h1>Enquiry Form</h1>
          <table border="0" align="center">
            <form name="form" action="email.php" id="form" method="post">
              <tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Name</td>
                  <td>
                    <input name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" value="">
                  </td>
                </tr>

                <<tr>
                  <td>Email</td>
                  <td>
                    <input name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text" value="">
                  </td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td>Phone</td>
                <td>
                  <input name="phone" placeholder="phonenumber" type="text" value="">
                </td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td>Message</td>
                <td>
                  <textarea name="msg" placeholder="Type your text here..."></textarea>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
                <input id="send" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
              </td>
              </tr>
            </form>
          </table>

        </div>
        <!--end enquiry-->
      </div>
      <!--end con-->
      <div id="footer">
        <!--start footer-->
        copyrights &copy; to WWW.abcpvt.com
        <img src="../task/photo/fb.png" alt="fb" />
        <img src="../task/photo/ln.png" alt="tweet" />
        <img src="../task/photo/tw.png" alt="linkedin" />
      </div>
      <!--end footer-->








    </div>
    <!--end wrapper-->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Make your code more beautiful by following the proper indentation. It can also help to find the parent of the elements.

Comment: Hope your footer is inside the wrapper . Could you please close the wrapper before the starting point of footer that will be make a footer as full width

Comment: You have asked the same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39137548/in-this-page-hover-is-not-working-i-dont-know-why-and-also-footer-is-not-taking/39142676#39142676) just yesterday and I did look into your code and gave a perfect answer. Though I will repeat that again

Answer (score 1):

The reasons for the footer not been 100%.

1. Its 100% per say but it becomes more than 100% after adding `padding:10px;`. To solve this you have to options. Its either you use `width:100%;` and add no `padding`, or you add `padding` and use `display:block;` instead of `width:100%;`
2. Secondly, you have a closing `div` missing for the `box`.

You have

```
<div class="container-fluid text-center bg-grey"><!--boxes-->
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="D:\task\photo\i.jpg" alt="Innovation">
        <p><strong>Innovation</strong></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="D:\task\photo\cr.png" alt="Creative">
        <p><strong>Creativity</strong></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="D:\task\photo\po.jpg" alt="Positive">
        <p><strong>Positivity</strong></p>
              </div>
        </div>
</div><!--end boxes-->
```

Instead of:

```
<div class="container-fluid text-center bg-grey"><!--boxes-->
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="D:\task\photo\i.jpg" alt="Innovation">
        <p><strong>Innovation</strong></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="D:\task\photo\cr.png" alt="Creative">
        <p><strong>Creativity</strong></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="D:\task\photo\po.jpg" alt="Positive">
        <p><strong>Positivity</strong></p>
              </div>
                </div>
    </div><!-- this is the missing closing div-->
</div><!--end boxes-->
```

3. Then lastly. You have to take away `float:left;` from the footer and use `clear:both;` instead. Doing this you will notice you have a better result.